# How are types compared in .NET? How does the CLR identify they are the same or different?

Tags: .net, types

<strike>How does the [`Type.Equals(Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ahwab82.aspx) compare types to know if they are the same or not?</strike>

The original question was being confused because of what I had here in the body as what I thought would direct the question. Forget that part. The question is in the title.

**EDIT:** Lasse V. Larksen posed my question best:

> "What makes up the identity of a .NET type"..."If I declare the exact same type, down to the namespace, in two different projects/assemblies, .NET consider them different, why?"

Comment: Why do you ask? (@SLaks have already answered your question, but I fear there is an underlying question here that you're not asking.)

Comment: I guess I'm almost asking "What is the Type Class"? I want to know how it is identified. Is there some identifier that is unique to each and every type?

Comment: @Richard: the problem with your original question is it has an answer (see @SLaks) that has been given. You have a different question in your comment which I guess is with the CLR representation.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: I want to know how types are compared. How does this work `Type == Type`???

Comment: @sixlettervariables: My question hasn't been answered yet. My question is in the title. The body of the question was hopefully to clarify, but apparently it has not. I have fixed the body of the question. Just pay attention to the title.  :-)

Comment: No, your question *has* been answered, your *unasked* question hasn't. The way the .NET runtime compares types is the way @SLaks have shown, that's from the (reference) source code. There is no other way or meaning to that code. Since that obviously doesn't answer your question, then you've asked the wrong question.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: How would you suggest I ask the question? I obviously don't know how to ask it . . .

Comment: "What makes up the identity of a .NET type" would be a better way, in my opinion, citing examples like the one I had, ie. "If I declare the exact same type, down to the namespace, in two different projects/assemblies, .NET consider them different, why?" to get the answer you seek. Again, I would like to know what you intend to use the knowledge for since I've seen quite a few number of questions that went down this very path before and ended up in quite different alleys when prodded for this.

Comment: (you should verify my claim by the way, just so that you can see for yourself, create 3 projects in one solution, where 1 of them reference the other 2, and then declare the same type in those other two, and in the one that references them, grab the Type object (you need to locate them through reflection since you now have ambiguous types) and check to make sure they're not comparing equal)

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Thanks for sticking with me on this question. You did help me get my answer by prodding for the correct question. That is exactly what I wanted, and I think SLaks gave it to me with the TypeHandle (see his comment). I ask simply to understand. I need to visualize everything in order to understand (or better yet, grok), and so I want to know what happens in a type comparison. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECMA-335 Common Language Infrastructure Partitions I and II dictate that each type will be known by a given *type signature*. It states how IL represents this signature and how the Virtual Execution System should interpret the signature, but it leaves how a conformant runtime implementation must actually **implement** this *type signature* up to the implementation (as far as I can tell).

> New types—value types and reference types—are introduced into the CTS via type declarations expressed in metadata. In addition, metadata is a structured way to represent all information that the CLI uses to locate and load classes, lay out instances in memory, resolve method invocations, translate CIL to native code, enforce security, and set up runtime context boundaries.

However, to your question, regardless of how `UnderlyingSystemType` is actually implemented it will correlate to a unique reference using the containing:

- Assembly
- Module
- Namespace
- Parent Types (if any)
- The Type itself

Partition II has the physical metadata for a `TypeDef` (section 22.37) which encodes this information.

Partition III contains the IL which represents loading a metadata token, known as a `RuntimeHandle` onto the stack. There are different handles for types, methods, and fields depending on the token given to the IL instructions.

Comment: What part of those is it pieces (assembly, module, namespace, etc.) of indentification is it using to make up the signature? Is it using the names of those pieces of identification?

Comment: The names of all of those contribute to the unique signature. It is up to the runtime to provide the mapping from the `typespec` to a `RuntimeTypeHandle`. As far as I can find in the standards the only requirement is the `RuntimeTypeHandle` fit onto the CLR stack.

Answer (score 4):

It's implemented like this:  (from the reference source)

```
public virtual bool Equals(Type o)
{ 
    if ((object)o == null) 
        return false;

    return (Object.ReferenceEquals(this.UnderlyingSystemType, o.UnderlyingSystemType));
}
```

Comment: Thanks SLaks. That's one level down, but still abstract. I want to know how it knows! lol What is the representation of the type that it can compare them to.

Comment: When you get the `Type` object for a type, and then get the `Type` object for another type, it simply uses reference comparisons to check if the two are the same object. In other words, every type gets its own `Type` object, and they all "act like singletons". If you want more detail you have to ask more detailed, like ... again ... *why do you ask*?

Comment: @Richard: It's magic.  `UnderlyingSystemType` returns `this`.

Comment: `internal RuntimeType() { throw new NotSupportedException(); }`

Comment: For instance, and here I'm just guessing as to your motive, but if, say, you redefine a type in two distinct assemblies (ie. projects), but keep the types identical right down to the namespaces, your question might be why the two aren't comparing equal. The answer to *that* question would be that the assembly is part of the identity of the type.

Comment: @Lasse V. Klarsen: Ok now we're getting somewhere. What is the identity of the type? Is it a hash of the AssemblyName (or strong Name) + Namespace + TypeName?

Comment: @SLaks: You're killin' me!  LOL

Comment: In order to investigate the magic, you'll probably need to look at the native parts of the Rotor source.  I believe it's based on a TypeHandle, generated by the CLR or the JITter.

Comment: Ok I think RuntimeTypeHandle is what I'm looking for. Any resources for investigating this some more?

Comment: The Rotor source is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
    return (((o != null) && (o is Type)) && (this.UnderlyingSystemType == ((Type) o).UnderlyingSystemType));
}
```

This is from the latest reflected source.

Comment: Thanks, but `UnderlyingSystemType` still just gets you a type, so there's just another comparison of types there!

Comment: Not quite, its a `==`, reference comparison, not `Equals` method.  So it's really checking whether the instance of the underlying type matches exactly.